# Can't get Ember.js to render properties from objects in controller

Tags: ember.js, javascript-framework

Total Noob question here. My apologies for the simplicity, and I've skimmed hundreds of Ember-tagged posts here looking for an answer. But it appears to be too primitive for anyone to have bothered asking before...

I'm starting from scratch with Ember. I did Andy Matthews' EmberTweets tutorial, which worked fine. I'm trying to use that as a basis for my first Ember app, which is painfully simple; but I'm stuck on the most basic of steps. I appear to have a functioning controller, and am seemingly adding new objects to it successfully. But I cannot for the life of me get my view to render the properties of those objects. The basic view renders out, but not the data from the controller, which I'm just trying to access with a simple `#each`. I get *no errors* in any browser console.

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xmlilley/ksjZp/5/).

I've tried adding objects to the controller in three different ways in my example, to see if that helps. I can successfully access from the console the properties of the objects by inspecting the content array, or with something like FilterMenus.MenusController.content.objectAt(2).get('menu_name'). Apparently, the data is right where it's supposed to be.

But still nothing appears in my template when I try to render out any of the properties, such as: `{{menu_name}}`. What am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the other answers, you have to declare your app as a global variable (by omitting the `var`).

Besides that, you are not calling `this._super()` inside your `FilterMenus.menusController`'s `init` method. This is required to setup the `Ember.ArrayController` correctly, so modifying the `content` will work.

Besides these two issues, your code looks fine. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/HPkHt/.

Comment: Thanks, @pangratz! Very much appreciate your extensive contributions here about Ember.

Comment: Since the app declaration is occurring in global scope, isn't it a global variable anyway, even with `var`? (I understand that there is a technical difference between the two methods of declaration, which generally has no side-effects other than in scope. Is it those secondary differences - rather than globality or lack thereof - that makes the difference here?)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Ember's big problem with your code is that your `Application` is defined as a `var` so it can't be accessed from the template. Removing the `var` keyword helped.

For some reason though, that wasn't quite enough and I had to add a

```
this.set('content', []);
```

as the first line of your init function to get it to work. I've never had to do this before so I'm not sure if it's jsFiddle doing something. If anyone has some light to shed on this, I'd be keen to hear it.

Comment: Yeah, I had also tried removing the var keyword, but didn't get anywhere with that. But while we're on the subject: I noticed that Ember app definitions never seem to be defined as vars. Why not? What else are they?

Comment: @XMLilley Apps are declared as global objects, so they can be accessed inside templates and global bindings like `nameBinding: 'App.name'` can be resolved.

Comment: @Drew `this.set('content', []);` is needed, because `this._super()` isn't called inside the `init` method of the `FilterMenus.menusController`. But this is needed to setup the observers on the `content`, ...

Comment: @pangratz Of course! That makes sense. Thanks for enlightening me!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Remove "var" from FilterMenus declaration:

   ```
   FilterMenus = Em.Application.create();
   ```
2. Change the implementation of `menusController.addMenu` to be:

   ```
   addMenu: function(menu) {
       this.content.push(menu);
   },
   ```

This got me the two menu names to show up after "Select Country" and the explanatory paragraph:

```
countries
countries2
```

Ember didn't seem to know what `this.pushObject(menu);` was. Pushing directly to the controller's content array will always work, though.

Comment: One shouldn't access properties on an `Ember.Object` directly, so to guarantee correctly working bindings `this.content` should be `this.get('content')`.